# Flash Game does not work unless you play the swf with CS5 installed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm making a platform game, and the game runs perfectly fine as a swf, as long as Flash CS5 is installed.  It won't even work if CS4 is installed.

When the swf is played standalone, or embedded in a browser (tested on multiple machines).  The collision detection does not work well, and the play simply falls endlessly.  Has anyone experienced their code messing up somehow when run in similar situations that could provide some insight?

Comment: player version in publish settings? did you try to click the play option in flashplayer context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the test machines are running Flash Player 10.0+ or alternatively, publish the swf in compatibility mode for Flash player 9 or whatever your target minimum requirement is.